# Merge Table - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-merge

So I have this table with hierarchy data

- bi_ods.table1 (source)

| part1 | part2 | part3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1A | 2A | 3B |
| 1B | 1A | 3B |

Truncating and inserting on a stored procedure, the information is coming from some other tables that also are doing the same truncate / insert thing.

I want to create a catalogue that would looked like this:

- bi_ods.cat_table1  (target)

| id | part1 | part2 | part3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1A | 2A | 3B |
| 2 | 1B | 1A | 3B |

only that merges when new information on source is inserting.

for example:

- Source Updated Table

| part1 | part2 | part3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1A | 2A | 3B |
| 1B | 1A | 3B |
| 1A | 2B | 3C |

- Target Updated Table

| id | part1 | part2 | part3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1A | 2A | 3B |
| 2 | 1B | 1A | 3B |
| 3 | 1A | 1B | 3C |

I'm having trouble creating the ID'S.

I tried the .nextval and sequence thing but the process runs everyday and it updates like this

| id | part1 | part2 | part3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1A | 2A | 3B |
| 5 | 1B | 1A | 3B |
| 6 | 1A | 1B | 3C |

ID's are changing and incrementing every day but I need them to be always the same.

Should I use rownum to assign an unique ID? or what is the best practice I can use for what I'm trying to reach.

Thank you! Feedback is welcome.

Comment: The `MERGE` should not handle the `ID`at all. Make followup `UPDATE` that *fills* the newly inserted records with `ID` starting from `max(id)+1`

Comment: You need some identifying columns to merge on. Then it should be `when not matched then insert (id, ...) values(seq.nextval, ...)`. Or for insert-only scenario it would be better to do `select <cols> from source minus select <cols> from target` and assign `nextval` to the result of set difference